How to tell VS Code where is Qt dlls to use when launching my app
I'm using VS Code with "C/C++", "CMake Tools" and "Qt Official" extensions to build a simple console Qt app. The main.cpp is just printing "Hello, world" message. After building, console (with name "CMake/Launch") shows that it launching my app:
PS C:\Sumbur\QtExample\build\Debug> ."C:/Sumbur/QtExample/build/Debug/myApp.exe"

Which doesn't output anything and shows no errors. I've found that my app is just cann't find Qt's DLLs - after executing windeployqt which copies all needed libraries, the app works properly and VS Code shows output. How to tell VS Code to accompany my app with DLLs how, for example, Qt Creator does, without copying this Dlls to build folder?

If you static link to the DLLs then they need to be in the same folder as the EXE, or in a folder on the system search path. Otherwise you will have to load them manually at runtime from whatever folder you want. That is just how DLLs work.

@RemyLebeau. I'm linking dynamically. That was the question, how to tell VS Code to load Dlls to simulate Qt Qreator's behaviour.

You can't link dynamically. You can only link statically, or you can delay-load (if your linker supports that). Otherwise, you can load dynamically via explicit calls to LoadLibrary() (which delay-loading does behind the scenes). So, what are you actually trying to use?

AFAIK, if your application is linked against the Qt's libraries and it cannot find the DLLs when being started, you would get an error message. What makes you say "[you]'ve found that [your] app is just cann't find Qt's DLLs". On that note, your question would benefit from some revision for grammar and punctuation. The above is not the only sentence I am struggling to read (another example: "How to tell [...] how [...]") and the result is that I don't even know which scenario works for you and which doesn't.

@RemyLebeau I wonder what man ld means when it mentions dynamic linking in a hundred or so places. My guess is it's the same exact thing you mean when you say delay-loading, but what do I know.

@Atmo "you would get an error message" You may or may not get one, depending on your toolchain, shell and who knows what else.

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/debug-launch.md#debug-using-a-launchjson-file you'll need to set the path environment variable to the folder containing the dlls

@n.m.couldbeanAI man ... anything is for non-Windows documentation, but several things in the OP's question imply Windows is being used instead.

@RemyLebeau strange, how do I run gcc and ld on Windows every single day?

Firstly I meant Windows in the question, but Linux will not be excess. About linking - I didn't understand it complitely too. Isn't there a dynamic linker which should find symbols in dynamic library at runtime?

Thanks to Alan Birtles. The PATH environment should be added to launch config:
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "My application",
        "type": "cppvsdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${command:cmake.getLaunchTargetDirectory}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [
                {
                    // add the directory where our target was built to the PATHs
                    // it gets resolved by CMake Tools:
                    "name": "PATH",
                    "value": "${env:PATH}:${command:cmake.getLaunchTargetDirectory}"
                }
            ],
        "externalConsole": false
      }
    ]

I don't understand why some people answer in comments instead of posting answers, so I did it myself just to close the topic.
Update: Here is my CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(MyFirstQt)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(Qt6_DIR "C:/Dev/Qt/6.8.0/msvc2022_64/lib/cmake/Qt6")
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
qt_standard_project_setup()

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
    ../src/main.cpp
)

qt_add_executable(myApp MANUAL_FINALIZATION ${PROJECT_SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(myApp PRIVATE
    Qt6::Core
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS myApp
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

qt_finalize_executable(myApp)

Qt's bin folder aslo is in PATH var, but I didn't replaced hard-coded path to in yet.

I'm confused how this solves the problem how the question requests though... "How to tell VS Code to accompany my app with DLLs how, for example, Qt Creator does, without copying this Dlls to build folder?". presumably this solution means the required DLLs are in the same directory as your executable target in the build tree. so either your question was requesting a constraint that your buildsystem configuration already made unnecessary, or your solution implies that you changed your buildsystem configuration to break that requirement?

I am quite confused that the line "program": "${command:cmake.getLaunchTargetDirectory}", actually works for you. a directory is not an executable target file.

@starball. I'm using VS Code just a few days and I use CMake just for a 2 weeks, so I don't understand deeply how this solution works, but it really works. As comment to code snippet says, this line allows CMake Tools find the Qt libraries. If it interesting to you, I will add a CMakeLists.txt which, who knows, may help.
